# Significance of piece index in bittorrent file transfer?

Tags: bittorrent

I am studying the file transfer using bittorrent protocol and is interested to know whether the `piece index` associated with each piece has any significance in the rearrangement of the pieces. Howe is this `piece index` assigned? Also is their some other way apart from using the hash value in `.torrent` file to rearrange the pieces?

Comment: Isn't there any one to help me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The relevant meta information

The metadata of a torrent includes sufficient information to reassemble and verify the data the torrent describes regardless of the order the data arrives.  The full definition can be found [here](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html), and for your question there are some important parts.

> **info** This maps to a dictionary, with keys described below.

and

> **pieces** maps to a string whose length is a multiple of 20. It is to be subdivided into strings of length 20, each of which is the SHA1 hash of the piece at the corresponding index.

and

> For the purposes of the other keys, the multi-file case is treated as only having a single file by concatenating the files in the order they appear in the files list.

and finally

> **piece length** maps to the number of bytes in each piece the file is split into. For the purposes of transfer, files are split into fixed-size pieces which are all the same length except for possibly the last one which may be truncated. piece length is almost always a power of two, most commonly 2 18 = 256 K (BitTorrent prior to version 3.2 uses 2 20 = 1 M as default).

### The result

Taken all together.  There is an assumption that the underlying data that a *.torrent* describes is in order from piece *0* to piece *NumPieces*.  All of the pieces will be exactly the same length, expect for possibly the last one and thus the **piece_index** X **piece_size** will give the offset in bytes from the beginning to where that piece fits in the data.  Multiple files are treated as if they're all concatenated together.  Each piece hash is located at **piece_index** X **20** bytes from the beginning of **pieces**. Now since **pieces** is located in the **info** section, if you rearrange the pieces by changing their index, this will change the SHA1 hash of the info section and thus the infoHash, which changes the torrent.  This is by design so the authenticity of the data is can be validated.  Practically speaking, it would be impossible to forge or accidentally reassemble pieces in the wrong order because the infoHash is the final check that **pieces** is correct and **pieces** is the check that the data is correct.

Comment: Thank u for that information.also is there  something similar to piece index if we use `micro torrent protocol` instead of `bittoreent protocol`...while capturing packets using `wireshark` of this scenario, it shows no such information.

Comment: UTorrent uses the same protocol and ideas.

Comment: Then what is the main differenc between the two... sorry to ask questions again and again..but really interested to know

Comment: Well [uTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9CTorrent) is a client, THE windows client, really.  It was created by BitTorrent the company. There are a number of compatible clients all supporting BitTorrent the protocol, and over time, other clients adopted each others strategies and extensions and they are all formalized as beps.

Comment: Well... i m not asking about the bittorrent client uTorrent.but about the uTP protocol that works above UDP during file transfer.

Comment: Oh ok.  Well so uTP is covered by [bep 29](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0029.html) and is referred to by bep 3 as one of the means of transmitting data.  Bep 3 (BitTorrent) covers the control messages "transmit this piece to me" while bep 29 (uTP) covers "here's the data for that piece you told me to transmit."

Comment: So there wont be any messages similar to `REQUEST`, `PIECE` or `HAVE` in uTP??Then how will we understand which piece is transferred without the hash value check.